# Codeception. Webdriver doesn't see localhost

Tags: docker, webdriver, localhost, codeception

Could you help me.
I use Codeception with Webdriver for my project

Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.3
Powered by PHPUnit 9.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

acceptance.suite.yaml:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
              url: 'https://localhost:8888'
              browser: chrome
              clear_cookies: true
              port: 4444
              capabilities:
                  browser: chrome
                  goog:chromeOptions:
                      w3c: false
```

Docker:

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --rm selenium/standalone-chrome
```

I can see my localhost in Browser. If i instead localhost:8888 use external site all right. But by testing i have "This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect".
Test is very simple:

```
<?php

class FirstCest
{
    public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->wait(5);        
        $I->makeScreenshot();
        I->see('Home');
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: looks like docker issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a URL host and port tweak to your `acceptance.suite.yml` since you are using a dockerized Selenium container to view your local website:

```yaml
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
              url: 'https://host.docker.internal:8888'
```

**Note:** If you are using Docker on Linux, your URL should instead be: 'https://172.17.0.1:8888'

You will then want to open that port in your dockerized Selenium container:

```sh
docker run \
-p 4444:4444 \
-p 8888:8888 \ # I'm new!
-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm \
--rm selenium/standalone-chrome
```